# What kind of larvae are these?

Tags: entomology, species-identification

My uncle was helping us spray the garage for ants, and he stumbled across a huge batch of some type of larvae. According to him...

> "It looked like a long, narrow clump of mud. When I broke it open, all of these larvae fell out. Whatever bugs were inside scattered pretty quickly!"

- **Geography:** We're in Los Angeles, CA (southwestern USA)
- **Season:** It's late summer here (early September)

**Exhibit A:** The pile of larvae...

[image: larvae]

**Exhibit B:** A similar husk of "mud" found in our garage. When it was shattered, nothing fell out...

[image: similar empty husk]

My uncle thinks it's termites... I'm certainly hoping it isn't.

Comment: Not a bug guy, but it *does* look like termites.

Comment: Sorry, but its termite larvae.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it is termites larvae. For more info check this :  Termites follow the typical life cycle of insects that have a gradual life cycle: they begin as eggs, and then enter nymphal to adult stages. In termite development, newly hatched termites are sometimes referred to as “larvae,” which is not to be confused with the larvae of complete metamorphosis insects like flies.

Termite larvae typically hatch within a few weeks. They are approximately the same size as the eggs from which they hatched and are immediately tended to by worker termites. They often comprise a large part of a termite colony.

Similar to other insect young, termite larvae go through a series of molts, during which they shed their skins. From the larval stage, termite larvae may evolve into other members of the colony’s castes.

If you suspect you have termite activity in or near your home, contact a pest control professional. Termite damage can go undetected and result in significant financial loss from their damage. A termite inspector can inspect a home for signs of activity and conditions that are attractive to termites. They also can offer services to treat and protect the home from potential future damage.

[image]

Comment: Bummer... certainly not what I wanted to hear, but seems to be the consensus. Thanks!

Comment: **UPDATE:** Inspector came today and said "yep, you've got subterranean termites"... so it's officially official.